# difference between HttpException and other Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i can't figure out what is difference between HttpException  and other exceptions in asp mvc,
based on asp helper HttpException means  **Describes an exception that occurred during the processing of HTTP requests.**
it says **during the processing of HTTP requests** in that case does not other exceptions occurr during HTTP requests?

Comment: It looks like you have an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do, why do you want to know this? Also, what do you mean by _"other exceptions occurred during HTTP requests"_?

Comment: say we have requested a page that does not exist then an HttpException is occurred but if we have a programmatic problem then kind of exception is defined based on our problem, okay? i want to know why we can not call the sec exception as HttpException?

Comment: You can perfectly wrap exceptions that occur in your code in an HttpException. Then make it a 500 - internal server error. The question is why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing of a HTTP request can raise other exceptions - it depends on what methods you are calling.

For example a [BinaryRead()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) raises an `ArgmentOutOfRangeException`.

You need to look at the exceptions raised by each method and decide whether you can sensibly trap them or whether you have to let them propagate.